# Create sql server functions from an assembly dll automatically

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have several functions in an assembly dll named `UserFunctions.dll`, for example :

```
public static partial class VariousFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
    public static SqlBoolean RegexMatch(SqlString expression, SqlString pattern)
    {
      ...
    }

    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
    public static SqlInt32 WorkingDays(SqlDateTime startDateTime, SqlDateTime endDateTime)
    {
      ...
    }

    [SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
    public static SqlString getVersion()
    {
      ...
    }

    ...
}
```

And I want to generate the sql script with a c# function, to create or update automatically all functions with attribute `SqlFunction` contained in this dll.
This sql script should look like this :

```
-- Delete all functions from assembly 'UserFunctions'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'DROP FUNCTION ' + STUFF(
            (
                SELECT
                    ', ' + QUOTENAME(assembly_method) 
                FROM
                    sys.assembly_modules
                WHERE
                    assembly_id IN (SELECT assembly_id FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = 'UserFunctions')
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
-- SELECT @sql
IF @sql IS NOT NULL EXEC sp_executesql @sql


-- Create all functions from assembly 'UserFunctions'
CREATE FUNCTION RegexMatch(@expression NVARCHAR(MAX), @pattern NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS BIT 
    AS EXTERNAL NAME UserFunctions.VariousFunctions.RegexMatch;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION WorkingDays(@startDateTime DATETIME, @endDateTime DATETIME) RETURNS INTEGER 
    AS EXTERNAL NAME UserFunctions.VariousFunctions.WorkingDays;
GO  
 CREATE FUNCTION getVersion() RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 
    AS EXTERNAL NAME UserFunctions.VariousFunctions.getVersion;
GO
```

The first part is very simple, but for the second part this is probably possible using the reflection methods of the classes Type, MethodInfo and ParameterInfo.
Someone has already done this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested and debugged it :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Assembly clrAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Path\to\your\assembly.dll");
  string sql = CreateFunctionsFromAssembly(clrAssembly, permissionSetType.UNSAFE);
  File.WriteAllText(sqlFile, sql);
}


/// <summary>
/// permissions available for an assembly dll in sql server
/// </summary>
public enum permissionSetType { SAFE, EXTERNAL_ACCESS, UNSAFE };


/// <summary>
/// generate sql from an assembly dll with all functions with attribute SqlFunction
/// </summary>
/// <param name="clrAssembly">assembly object</param>
/// <param name="permissionSet">sql server permission set</param>
/// <returns>sql script</returns>
public static string CreateFunctionsFromAssembly(Assembly clrAssembly, permissionSetType permissionSet)
{
    const string sqlTemplate = @"
      -- Delete all functions from assembly '{0}'
      DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
      SET @sql = 'DROP FUNCTION ' + STUFF(
        (
            SELECT
                ', ' + assembly_method 
            FROM
                sys.assembly_modules
            WHERE
                assembly_id IN (SELECT assembly_id FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = '{0}')
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '')
      IF @sql IS NOT NULL EXEC sp_executesql @sql
      GO

      -- Delete existing assembly '{0}' if necessary
      IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = '{0}')
        DROP ASSEMBLY {0};
      GO

      {1}
      GO

      -- Create all functions from assembly '{0}'
    ";
    string assemblyName = clrAssembly.GetName().Name;

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.AppendFormat(sqlTemplate, assemblyName, CreateSqlFromAssemblyDll(clrAssembly, permissionSet));

    foreach (Type classInfo in clrAssembly.GetTypes())
    {
        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in classInfo.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly))
        {
            if (Attribute.IsDefined(methodInfo, typeof(SqlFunctionAttribute)))
            {
                StringBuilder methodParameters = new StringBuilder();
                bool firstParameter = true;
                foreach (ParameterInfo paramInfo in methodInfo.GetParameters())
                {
                    if (firstParameter)
                         firstParameter = false;
                    else
                        methodParameters.Append(", ");
                    methodParameters.AppendFormat(@"@{0} {1}", paramInfo.Name, ConvertClrTypeToSql(paramInfo.ParameterType));
                }
                string returnType = ConvertClrTypeToSql(methodInfo.ReturnParameter.ParameterType);
                string methodName = methodInfo.Name;
                string className = (classInfo.Namespace == null ? "" : classInfo.Namespace + ".") + classInfo.Name;
                string externalName = string.Format(@"{0}.[{1}].{2}", assemblyName, className, methodName);
                sql.AppendFormat(@"CREATE FUNCTION {0}({1}) RETURNS {2} AS EXTERNAL NAME {3};"
                                , methodName, methodParameters, returnType, externalName)
                   .Append("\nGO\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return sql.ToString();
}


/// <summary>
/// Generate sql script to create assembly
/// </summary>
/// <param name="clrAssembly"></param>
/// <param name="permissionSet">sql server permission set</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string CreateSqlFromAssemblyDll(Assembly clrAssembly, permissionSetType permissionSet)
{
    const string sqlTemplate = @"
      -- Create assembly '{0}' from dll
      CREATE ASSEMBLY [{0}] 
        AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
        FROM 0x{2}
        WITH PERMISSION_SET = {1};
    ";

    StringBuilder bytes = new StringBuilder();
    using (FileStream dll = File.OpenRead(clrAssembly.Location))
    {
        int @byte;
        while ((@byte = dll.ReadByte()) >= 0)
            bytes.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", @byte);
    }
    string sql = String.Format(sqlTemplate, clrAssembly.GetName().Name, permissionSet, bytes);

    return sql;
}


/// <summary>
/// Convert clr type to sql type
/// </summary>
/// <param name="clrType">clr type</param>
/// <returns>sql type</returns>
private static string ConvertClrTypeToSql(Type clrType)
{
    switch (clrType.Name)
    {
        case "SqlString":
            return "NVARCHAR(MAX)";
        case "SqlDateTime":
            return "DATETIME";
        case "SqlInt16":
            return "SMALLINT";
        case "SqlInt32":
            return "INTEGER";
        case "SqlInt64":
            return "BIGINT";
        case "SqlBoolean":
            return "BIT";
        case "SqlMoney":
            return "MONEY";
        case "SqlSingle":
            return "REAL";
        case "SqlDouble":
            return "DOUBLE";
        case "SqlDecimal":
            return "DECIMAL(18,0)";
        case "SqlBinary":
            return "VARBINARY(MAX)";
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(clrType.Name + " is not a valid sql type.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do the following: 
from visual studio, go to file > new project… then select SQL SERVER from template

[image]

take properties from your project

[image]

mention that in project settings, you can determine your "target platform"
and in SQLCLR, you can select your programming language

[image]

add a new item (SQL CLR C# user defined function) to your project

[image]

write your functions

[image]

after writing your code, right click on your project and first build your project and then publish it to you sql server

[image]

in the next window, setup your connection to your sql server and your database

[image]

after finishing, you can see that proper assembly and function has been created 
in your database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be using reflection in a known function that is compiled in the dll (in case it's yours) or in a CLR dll which you can create and reference. There you can use the full fledged REGEX support of .NET to return to SQL SERVER the matched names you need to create the functions.

This is a bit of a workaround, but I am not aware of native TSQL method to use .NET reflection

**-EDIT-**

if you need to create a TSQL script from .NET you can use something like this (undebugged, but most stuff should be there)

```
public string encode(Type containerClass, string SSRVassemblyName)
    {
        string proTSQLcommand="";
        MethodInfo[] methodName = containerClass.GetMethods();
        foreach (MethodInfo method in methodName)
        {
            proTSQLcommand += "CREATE FUNCTION ";
            if (method.ReflectedType.IsPublic)
            {
                bool hasParams = false;
                proTSQLcommand += method.Name +"(";
                ParameterInfo[] curmethodParams = method.GetParameters();
                if (curmethodParams.Length > 0)
                    for (int i = 0; i < curmethodParams.Length; i++)
                    {
                        proTSQLcommand +=(hasParams?",":"")+ String.Format("@{0} {1}",curmethodParams[i].Name,CLRtypeTranscoder(curmethodParams[i].ParameterType.Name)) ;
                        hasParams = true;
                    }
                proTSQLcommand += (hasParams ? "," : "") + String.Format("@RetVal {0} OUT", CLRtypeTranscoder(method.ReturnType.Name));

            }
            //note that I have moved the result of the function to an output parameter 
            proTSQLcommand += "RETURNS INT ";
            //watch this! the assembly name you have to use is the one of SSRV, to reference the one of the CLR library you have to use square brackets as follows
            proTSQLcommand += String.Format("AS EXTERNAL NAME {0}.[{1}.{2}].{3}; GO ",SSRVassemblyName, GetAssemblyName(containerClass.Name),containerClass.Name,method.Name);
        }
        return proTSQLcommand;
    }
    public string CLRtypeTranscoder(string CLRtype)
    { //required as the mapping of CLR type depends on the edition of SQL SERVER you are using
        switch (CLRtype.ToUpper())
        {
            case "STRING":
                return "VARCHAR(MAX)";
            case "INT":
                return "INT";
        }
        throw new   ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
    public static String GetAssemblyName(String typeName)
    {
        foreach (Assembly currentassemblAssy in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            Type t = currentassemblAssy.GetType(typeName, false, true);
            if (t != null) { return currentassemblAssy.FullName; }
        }

        return "not found";
    }
```

Comment: perhaps I have not so well explained the problem, but I want to generate the sql previously described using a c# function, not a TSQL method.